# Do I need to encapsulation a collections but expose a Enumerator?

Tags: c#, oop

For example,I have a collection in a class,and I don't want users to modify the collection (x.Add/x.Remove/x=xx)but sometimes users have to foreach the collection,so Do I have to expose a enumerable like #1 or fully expose collection self like #2?

#1

```
public class TileGrid {  
        List<int> list;

        public ref struct ListEnumerable {
            readonly TileGrid tileGrid;
            public ListEnumerable(TileGrid tileGrid) {
                this.tileGrid = tileGrid;
            }
            public List<int>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
                => tileGrid.list.GetEnumerator();
        }
        public ListEnumerable ForeachList()
            => new ListEnumerable(this);
}
```

#2

```
public class TileGrid {  
        public List<int> list{get;private set;}
}
```

some friends told me IReadonlyList<> to solve it,but after my test,this way will alloc 40b in heap.here is the benchmark

```
public class TTT {
    public List<int> list = new List<int>();
    public IReadOnlyList<int> readonlyList => list;

    public ref struct ListEnumerable {
        readonly TTT tileGrid;
        public ListEnumerable(TTT tileGrid) {
            this.tileGrid = tileGrid;
        }
        public List<int>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
            => tileGrid.list.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public ListEnumerable GetListEnumerable()
        => new ListEnumerable(this);

    public TTT() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class BenchMark {
    TTT ttt;

    public BenchMark() {
        ttt = new TTT();
    }
 
    [Benchmark]
    public void ForeachList() {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in ttt.list)
            i += item;
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public void ForeachReadonlyList() {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in ttt.readonlyList)
            i += item;
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public void ForeachRefStruct() {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in ttt.GetListEnumerable())
            i += item;
    } 
}
```

and result here

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ForeachList | 20.27 ns | 0.242 ns | 0.215 ns | - | - |
| ForeachReadonlyList | 76.01 ns | 0.420 ns | 0.328 ns | 0.0048 | 40 B |
| ForeachRefStruct | 19.76 ns | 0.202 ns | 0.189 ns | - | - |

Comment: why not have accessor like `IEnumerable<int> Enumerable => tileGrid;` ?

Comment: because there will be more than one collection in this class.

Comment: Or `IReadOnlyCollection<int> List => list;`. As for `there will be more than one collection in this class.`  add more such properties. A single line of code is a *lot* less than the 9 lines in your first example

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right, I think this is the correct answer,Sorry for that i don't know there is a interface like IReadOnlyCollection.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is just as good, if you only care about iteration. `IReadOnlyCollection` provides a `Count` property so callers don't have to iterate all members to get the count. There's also `IReadOnlyList<T>` which allows access by index

Comment: [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) imlements read-only `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` since .Net 4.5

Comment: But using IReadOnlyCollection to iteration will alloc 40b.

Comment: @liunliun Interesting, any source to back up this claim? On the other hand, do you care about such microoptimisation?

Comment: @orhtej2 yes i have update the question,and you can see the code

Comment: 40 bytes?! That's clearly unacceptable. Good that you've taken a look at this, before you know it applications might start using memory and all that... no but seriously, there may be circumstances where this is worth optimizing, but I'd expect them to be few and far between indeed. We're talking about a Gen 0 allocation for an iteration. It's not like those are going to quickly accumulate and balloon the memory footprint. Inasmuch as it's worth optimizing at all, it's probably something the framework authors would have to do, not a reason to avoid it on the developer end.

Comment: @liunliun After reading through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690327/memory-allocation-of-interface I'm still unsure on why that is. Have you benchmarked Release build?

Comment: the benchmark is work on release build

Comment: @orthej2: this is not boxing due to an interface (since `List` is a reference object itself); it's likely because the JIT cannot "see through" the enumerator allocation when going through `IReadOnlyCollection` and so fails to optimize it away. There is some cleverness on the JIT level for common enumeration scenarios, but this one is apparently not common enough to be grabbed by that. (Disclaimer: I've not actually dug into it myself to see where it's really coming from.)